# How to sort rows in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have the following in a sheet :

[image: example1]

I would like to sort it like this in another sheet in the same file:

[image: example2]

What I want to do is to import row whenever its column A has a certain value and import all the next empty rows but stop when Column A has any other value.
I hope I was clear with my explication. I would appreciate your help please

Ps: I have no control over dataA, it isn't a constant

Comment: Do you mean like this = filter(sort(A2:B, 2, true), A2:B<>''")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mine is the same

```
=ArrayFormula(query({if(B:B="","",vlookup(row(A:A),{if(A:A="","",row(A:A)),A:A},2,true)),A:B},"select Col2,Col3 where Col1='A'"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thaaanks a lot Tom. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to copy all rows from another sheet in the spreadsheet in which column A has the value `A` or it is empty. If that's the case, you can use this:

`=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet1!A1:B),"SELECT * WHERE A='A' or A='' ")`

#### Reference:

- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)
- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: unfortunately dataA is variable each time it has a value (phone number)

Comment: @biahuosisnice sorry I didn't understand your question before. I updated it. Please tell me if that works for you now.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({IF(B1:B="",,VLOOKUP(ROW(A1:A), 
 IF(A1:A<>"", {ROW(A1:A), A1:A}), 2, 1)), B1:B}, 
 "select Col2 where upper(Col1)='A'", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaaaaanks